# Universal Way to Know Router's Address

Tags: networking, router, netstat

How can I know what the router's address is when I am on multiple interface?
I know by using netstat -rn I can have the dominate interface's gateway, which is the router's address. But what about other interface.

For my case, I am on eth0 and wlan0 on different router, OS chooses eth0 as default, but is there a universal way that I can query an interface's router address?

```
$ netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan0

$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b4:b5:2f:32:f3:22  
      inet addr:192.168.1.132  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::b6b5:2fff:fe32:f322/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:22 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:53 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:3035 (3.0 KB)  TX bytes:9857 (9.8 KB)
      Interrupt:17 Memory:d4400000-d4420000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:569 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:569 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:53950 (53.9 KB)  TX bytes:53950 (53.9 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 60:67:20:00:56:6c  
      inet addr:192.168.2.115  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::6267:20ff:fe00:566c/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:8152 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:4030 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:6316155 (6.3 MB)  TX bytes:574275 (574.2 KB)
```

Comment: each interface is (typically) on a different network. do you want a **list of router addresses**? IPs or MACs?

Comment: I mean router ip

Answer (score 0):

Is not a complete solution, but you check `arp -n`.

```
ddd@mmm ~ $ arp -n
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx          ether   00:e0:1e:b4:12:42   C                     eth0
yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy          ether   00:14:78:52:28:d2   C                     wlan0
```

Comment: In my setup, I found multiple addresses under one interface, including router and some other peer, any clue on how to choose the right one?

Comment: I'm not sure, any ip can represent gateway address.

Answer (score 0):

To find the first hopan interface uses to reach the Internet:

```
ping -I <interface or ip of interface> -t 1 8.8.8.8
```

-t 1 - limits the packet to ttl of 1, meaning the packet will be killed by the first router, it attempts to go through.  That router will return a "Time to live exceeded" packet, showing the ip address of the device that generated that packet.

```
From 192.168.0.254 icmp_seq=1 Time to live exceeded
```

On windows the command is slightly differnt:

```
ping -S <ip address of interface> -i 1 8.8.8.8
```

-i 1 is the option to limit the ttl to 1 on windows, the reply will be:

```
Reply from 192.168.0.254: TTL expired in transit.
```

If you increase the number after -t/-i then you will get the nth hop the packet goes through.  This technique can be used if you do not have tracert, and you need to know the path a packet will take.

Please note, the route a packet takes on the internet and some lans can change each time a packet is sent.